# Relational Operators Will Not Function Properly In C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, logical-operators, relational-operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Input/Output Operations:
#define READ 10
#define WRITE 11

// Load/Store Operations:
#define LOAD 20
#define STORE 21

// Arithmetic Operations:
#define ADD 30
#define SUBTRACT 31
#define DIVIDE 32
#define MULTIPLY 33

//Transfer-of-control Operations:
#define BRANCH 40
#define BRANCHNEG 41
#define BRANCHZERO 42
#define HALT 43

void main_message();
void load(int *memory,int *instructionCounter);
void execute(int *instructionCounter, int memory[], int *instructionRegister, int *operationCode, int *operand, unsigned int *accumulator);
void dump(int *memory);

int main()
{
    main_message();

    //Special Registers
    int memory[101] = {+0000};
    unsigned int accumulator = 0000;
    int instructionCounter = 00;
    unsigned int instructionRegister = 0000;
    int operationCode = 00;
    int operand = 00;


    load(memory,&instructionCounter);
    execute(&instructionCounter, memory, &instructionRegister, &operationCode, &operand, &accumulator);
    computer_dump(memory);
    return 0;
}
void main_message()
{
    puts("*** Welcome to Simpletron! ***");
    puts("*** Please enter your program one instruction ***");
    puts("*** (or data word) at a time. I will type the ***");
    puts("*** location number and a question mark (?).  ***");
    puts("*** You then type the word for that location. ***");
    puts("*** Type the sentinel -99999 to stop entering ***");
    puts("*** your program. ***");
    puts("");
    puts("");
}
void computer_dump(int *memory)
{
    //Special Computer Registers
    puts("REGISTERS:");
    printf("accumulator\t\t%+05d\n",0);
    printf("instructionCounter\t%02d\n",0);
    printf("instructionRegister\t%+05d\n",0);
    printf("operationCode\t\t%02d\n",0);
    printf("operand\t\t\t%02d\n",0);
    puts("");


    //Printing Memory
    puts("MEMORY:");
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        printf("\t%d",i);
    puts("");

    for(int i = 0; i<91; i+=10)
    {
      printf("%d\t",i);
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j ++)
      {
          printf("%+.04d\t",*(memory + (i+j)));
      }
      puts("");
    }
}
void load(int *memory,int *instructionCounter)
{
    //Goal load data into memory array using pointers
    while(1)
    {
        printf("%02d ?  ", *instructionCounter);
        scanf("%d", (memory + *instructionCounter));

        if(*(memory + *instructionCounter) == -99999)                                             // Checking if termination value has been entered
        {
            *(memory + *instructionCounter) = 00;
            break;
        }

        if(*(memory + *instructionCounter) < -9999 || *(memory + *instructionCounter) > 9999)                       // Checking if word is in range
        {
            *(memory + *instructionCounter) = 00;
            puts("Please type a word between the ranges of -9999 and +9999");
            continue;
        }
        *instructionCounter+=1;
    };

    puts("*** Program loading completed ***");
    puts("*** Program execution begins  ***");
    puts("");
    puts("");
}
void execute(int *instructionCounter, int memory[], int *instructionRegister, int *operationCode, int *operand, unsigned int *accumulator)
{
    puts("Performing the execution phase!");
    for (int i = 0; i <*instructionCounter; i++)
    {
        *instructionRegister = memory[i];
        *operationCode = *instructionRegister / 100;
        *operand = *instructionRegister % 100;

        // operation instructions
        if(*operationCode == READ)          // Input/Output operations
        {
            printf("? ");
            scanf("%d", &memory[*operand]);
        }
        else if(*operationCode == WRITE)
        {
            printf("%d",memory[*operand]);
        }
        else if(*operationCode == LOAD)     // Load/Store Operations
        {
            *accumulator = memory[*operand];
        }
        else if(*operationCode == STORE)
        {
            memory[*operand] = *accumulator;
        }
        else if(*operationCode == ADD)     // Arithmetic Operations
        {
            if (*accumulator + memory[*operand] < -9999 || *accumulator + memory[*operand] > 9999 )
            {
                puts("*** Operation resulted in a value outside the bounds of memory ***");
                puts("*** Simpletron execution abnormally terminated ***");
                break;
            }
            *accumulator+= memory[*operand];
            printf("Accumulator after addition operation performed: %d\n",*accumulator);
        }
        else if(*operationCode == SUBTRACT)
        {
             if (*accumulator - memory[*operand] < -9999 || (*accumulator - memory[*operand]) > 9999 )
            {
                puts("*** Operation resulted in a value outside the bounds of memory ***");
                puts("*** Simpletron execution abnormally terminated ***");
                break;
            }
            *accumulator -= memory[*operand];
        }
        else if(*operationCode == DIVIDE)
        {
            if (memory[*operand] == 0)                                       // Checking to see if number is undefined 
            {
                puts("*** Attempt to divide by Zero ***");                  
                puts("*** Simpletron execution abnormally terminated  ***");
                break;
            }
            *accumulator = *accumulator / memory[*operand];
        }
        else if(*operationCode == MULTIPLY)
        {
             if (*accumulator * memory[*operand] < -9999 || *accumulator * memory[*operand] > 9999 )
            {
                puts("*** Operation resulted in a value outside the bounds of memory ***");
                puts("*** Simpletron execution abnormally terminated ***");
                break;
            }
            *accumulator = *accumulator * memory[*operand];
        }
        else if(*operationCode == BRANCH)     // Transfer-Of-Control Operations
        {
            i = *operand;
        }
        else if(*operationCode == BRANCHNEG)
        {
            if(*accumulator < 0)
                i = *operand;
        }
        else if(*operationCode == BRANCHZERO)
        {
            if(*accumulator == 0)
                i = *operand;
        }
        else if(*operationCode == HALT)
        {
            puts("*** Simpletron execution terminated ***");
        }
    }
    puts("");
    puts("");
}
```

In the function labeled "execute" under the arithmetic operation **subtract** I attempt to perform a logical comparison between two relational operators. `*accumulator - memory[*operand] < -9999 || *accumulator - memory[*operand] > 9999`. The purpose of this comparison is to check if the calculation resulted in a total that is outside the bounds of memory. When I tested conditions that should have resulted in a logical 0 (false) I only got a logical 1 (True). The program works flawlessly when the subtraction operation results in a positive number. However, when a negative number is encountered, the program terminates when it should not. Does anyone know what is wrong with the logical operation? PS ( This program is the "Simpletron Compiler" challenge from the book titled "Programming in C").

Comment: Specifically which numbers cause it to get a logicla 1?

Comment: You'll want to add a 'catch-all' `else` to the end of the "decode" if/else ladder... "Illegal OpCode"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the declaration of `execute`, the argument `accumulator` has a type of `unsigned int *`. Therefore, when you dereference `accumulator`, the type is unsigned. When you mix unsigned and signed types in arithmetic operations, the result is treated as unsigned, thus `*accumulator - memory[*operand]` would become a huge **positive** number (larger than 9999) when it should be negative. This should be the reason that causes the condition to unexpectedly hold.

Therefore, it is better to cast `accumulator` to signed int before comparing with `memory[*operand] - 9999` and `memory[*operand] + 9999`.